# overloading abstract class method with class reference return generic type

Tags: typescript

```
// Welcome to the TypeScript Playground, this is a website
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class ServiceChecklistResponse {
}
class AnotherModel {
}

abstract class AbstractView {
        getJsonDataModelRef<T>() : Constructor<T> | null
    {
        return null;
    }
    getAnotherDataModel<T>(): Constructor<T> | null
    {
        return null
    }
}
class testView extends AbstractView {
    getJsonDataModelRef<ServiceChecklistResponse>() : Constructor<ServiceChecklistResponse> | null {
            return ServiceChecklistResponse;
    }
    getAnotherDataModel<AnotherModel>() : Constructor<AnotherModel> | null
    {
        return AnotherModel;
    }

}
```

```
Type 'typeof ServiceChecklistResponse' is not assignable to type 'Constructor<ServiceChecklistResponse>'.
  Type 'ServiceChecklistResponse' is not assignable to type 'ServiceChecklistResponse'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
    'ServiceChecklistResponse' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'ServiceChecklistResponse'.
Type 'typeof AnotherModel' is not assignable to type 'Constructor<AnotherModel>'.



  Type 'AnotherModel' is not assignable to type 'AnotherModel'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
    'AnotherModel' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'AnotherModel'.
```

Could someone shed light on why this problem occurs and how I can fix this? Yes it has to return a class reference because further down the food chain, a controller will be calling

```
const Model = myView.getJsonDataModelRef()
const foo = new Model()
```

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB5Zxw) what you're looking for?  It seems like you have the generics at the wrong scope; your classes need to be generic, not their methods.  If that works for you I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? If you reply, please mention @jcalz so I'm notified

Comment: many thanks! @jcalz that is what i am looking for- how do I promote your answer to solved?

Comment: I have to write up an actual answer post, which I will do when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in TypeScript, generic *types* and generic *functions*, and you have mixed them up.

---

On the one hand, there are generic *types*, where the generic type parameter is part of the type itself, and you need to specify the type parameter with a type argument in order to refer to the type at all:

```
type Foo<T> = (x: T) => T;
interface Bar<T> { y: T };
class Baz<T> { z: T; constructor(z: T) {this.z = z;} }
```

In the above, you can't say just mention `Foo`... you have to pass a type argument like `Foo<string>`, which now instantiates the type as the specific type `(x: string) => string`.  Essentially the implementer of the function gets to choose what type argument to set.  I can write a `Foo<string>` like `const f: Foo<string> = x => x.toUpperCase()` and I can write a `Foo<number>` like `const g: Foo<number> = x => x * 2;`.  If I am implementing the function and I want to choose the type argument, then I want a generic type, not a generic function.

---

On the other hand, there are also generic *functions*, where the generic type parameter is part of the call signature of the function, and you only need to specify the type parameter with a type argument when you *call* the function:

```
function foo<T>(x: T) { return x; }
interface Bar { bar<T>(y: T): T; }
class Baz { baz<T>(z: T) { return z; } }
```

In the above, the value `foo` has a specific type you can talk about: `typeof foo` is `<T>(x: T) => T`.  If you want to instantiate the generic type argument you can do so by calling the function like `foo<string>("someString")`, which returns a `string` (because now `T` has been specified as `string`) or you could use an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) like `foo<string>` to get a value of type `(x: string) => string`.  It is the *caller* of `foo` and not the *implementer* that chooses the type argument.  The function `foo()` has to be able to handle any `T` the caller wants to send.  I can't say that the function `(x: string) => x.toUpperCase()` is of type `typeof foo`.  If I want to write a function that handles any possible generic type parameter, then I want a generic function, not a generic type.

---

Looking at your code:

```
abstract class AbstractView {
  getJsonDataModelRef<T>(): Constructor<T> | null { return null; }
  getAnotherDataModel<T>(): Constructor<T> | null { return null }
}
```

apparently `AbstractView` is not a generic class, but it has two generic methods, `getJsonDataModelRef`, and `getAnotherdataModel`.  That means the *caller* of these methods gets to specify the type argument `T` without passing in any arguments at runtime (they are both methods of zero runtime arguments), and the implementation has to return a value of type `Constructor<T> | null`.  If the caller has a value `view` of type `AbstractView`, they could call `view.getJsonDataModelRef<IceCreamSundae>()` and get a `Constructor<IceCreamSundae> | null`, and then immediately call `view.getJsonDataModelRef<PickledHerring>()` and get a `Constructor<PickledHerring> | null`.  It seems quite unlikely that you could have a class that does this.  Well, unless it always returns `null`.

But this isn't your intent, right?  You want each instance of your class to be able to implement `getJsonDataModelRef()` and `getAnotherDataModel()` for particular generic type arguments chosen by the implementer.  So, it's not the *methods* that should be generic, but the *class*.

---

And so let's move the type arguments up out of the method call signatures, and onto the class itself:

```
abstract class AbstractView<J, D> {
  getJsonDataModelRef(): Constructor<J> | null {
    return null;
  }
  getAnotherDataModel(): Constructor<D> | null {
    return null
  }
}
```

Looks good.  Now when we subclass it, we can specify the type arguments (because in order to refer to `AbstractView` we need to pick those types)

```
class TestView extends AbstractView<ServiceChecklistResponse, AnotherModel> {
  getJsonDataModelRef(): Constructor<ServiceChecklistResponse> | null {
    return ServiceChecklistResponse;
  }
  getAnotherDataModel(): Constructor<AnotherModel> | null {
    return AnotherModel;
  }    
}
```

And now there's no errors.  Let's test it:

```
declare const myView: TestView;
const Model = myView.getJsonDataModelRef();
//const Model: Constructor<ServiceChecklistResponse> | null
if (!Model) throw new Error();
const foo = new Model();
// const foo: ServiceChecklistResponse
```

That's the behavior you want.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBxCwAqBPG0kG8BYAKCSQBcdkAxAe1oB4MA+JAXgKQA8AuJDJAF8A3CTIBLYOQgAnAGYJkAIRAymrfEix8BIsUngAbEFChIVAL3WcLO4QdrAo5GQFd45WjIAUt-gEpOcgALcSgAOgt2JAt7QSESQRJQSFhFVHRqV2B4MyJSJDlsj3FHQvp1b14AzhkIclcZYG44-UlpeXSVGU4AI1VK7QC7BIKjEzNLPpArFl8dQM06hqaYuNGk4mTwaDhEJAB5Whg8-RBe5xkEcgNjUyQAQQuXa4A1cQgAdwJ9MgBzeoAKSgjgAIiByCAALK0AAmEEMACUIHJKv4+ABhRyXdyeNQsJAAHyQwFchkMtXqjWapPJrQK-3qD2AtBCsnBkJh8MMaMx2JcuK81mJtIpSypq1FozIm02JEouCQWKcAo8QoJHGAXyQ3nCetUfygfBAwCwAG0ALqBNisDCiLbEcb3ADKsgAbuJEBjghB4ABrQxhcjI2DY5D5TZOszM1k+mRchE-Yhy4jnS7XW4TR7PK4ed5fBiAgA0SFBGn0APIwLBEOhcIRyLk3nRSv5bjVakBrBFZLFvyQy2pJN79plFaZLLZMg5de5zb5KvbeIYZaJw-JSbIZEHkt7+llJCj-Gg5Hz3wgXGkwFh0Zzbw+nwYrpkHq9Pv9gecIZgYZLManCaGOWBSVtWwAzoBjbzq2i6Cmoz6vhA3q+gGQbfmG3brn2DIDhKzQIZ6SHvqhX67GGo7Skglb-nGEH1oY0HKjiHYMDRsiAZhUr5FuuErM0bHxvRFEpim8LjHUDgqkgYBYGeOgnme9rwPySCAdEMlnuEoEguBtaQSizb2gA9EZylSYBC7McuBFvihn7BmRTgQJxe7EOIcg6gAhIBgQhDItDfFq3wAKIyP5Pj+EpKlyPQ0RBap9GGSQJmSc45S0HwNlEXZaGOVAEBAA)